# Remove more than 3 entries in the last 1 day in sql

Tags: mysql

If I have the following table,

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Liam | 2020-05-05 12:00:00 |
| John | 2020-12-15 03:45:00 |
| Ross | 2021-03-20 02:00:00 |
| Ross | 2021-03-20 02:05:00 |
| Ross | 2021-03-20 04:00:00 |
| Ross | 2021-03-20 04:30:00 |
| Ross | 2021-03-20 03:00:00 |
| Jane | 2021-03-20 02:00:00 |

Assume that `NOW()` gives `2021-03-20 10:00:00`.
I want to remove all rows other than first three(based on time) if the same person has more than 3 entries in the last 24 hours from right now.
So this table becomes,

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Liam | 2020-05-05 12:00:00 |
| John | 2020-12-15 03:45:00 |
| Ross | 2021-03-20 02:00:00 |
| Ross | 2021-03-20 02:05:00 |
| Ross | 2021-03-20 03:00:00 |
| Jane | 2021-03-20 02:00:00 |

Comment: Please post your query attempt and MySQL version.

Comment: You have a mismatch in your condition compared to your expected result. OR maybe my understanding is different. You said _"in the last 24 hours"_ but `Liam` and `John` records is way beyond that but you still show in result. But if the condition only effective to someone who _"3 entries in the last 24 hours from right now"_, which is "Ross", then what if the same person have records beyond 24 hours?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `table name` is `tbl_dates`.

So delete every rows which exists in today except the last rows after the first 3 rows (Nested `select`).

```sql
delete from tbl_dates as d1 where not exists (
    select tbl_tmp.`Date` from (
        select d2.`Date` from tbl_dates as d2 where d2.`Name`=d1.`Name` and date(d2.`Date`)=current_date() order by d2.`date` asc limit 0,3
    ) as tbl_tmp where tbl_tmp.`Date`=d1.`Date`
) and date(d1.`Date`)=current_date()
```

`tbl_tmp`: This subquery acted as a table for the first 3 rows of a person in today.

`not exists (select ...)`: This subquery acted as a condition to equal current delete statement row with the first 3 rows of a person in today.

**Updated**:

if You want to select in this condition you can use this:

```sql
select * from tbl_dates as d1 where exists (
    select tbl_tmp.`Date` from (
        select d2.`Date` from tbl_dates as d2 where d2.`Name`=d1.`Name` and date(d2.`Date`)=current_date() order by d2.`date` asc limit 0,3
    ) as tbl_tmp where tbl_tmp.`Date`=d1.`Date`
) or date(d1.`Date`)<>current_date()
```

MySql version which I Tested: `8.0.18`

Comment: I think OP meant to "remove it from results" only and not directly delete. Even so, your query doesn't seem to work. You can use [this fiddle to do some test run](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=68e1e223a085a4635a8ab0724bf8ed4a)

Comment: @FanoFN tnx for feedback, delete query only worked for delete statement, so I updated my answer for a select statement. [this fiddle with today's data in `ross` rows](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90dec136e35a2feb6408b9c70bf92cae)